# Firebase Storage is giving StorageException while trying to upload images

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload images to the new firebase storage service . It is throwing StorageException

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                           An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner
>   exception for server response.
>                                                                            Code: -13000 HttpResult: 400
>
> E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
>                                                                           java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
>                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzVi(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzVh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I too get this error but on very few phones.

Answer (score 9):

In your firebase console, go to the storage tab on the left. Click on the rules tab and set your rule to public. Use the following code to set it to public.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

This is good for testing purpose, however, you should secure your DB connection using authenticate users.

Answer (score 7):

In the google firebase this type of `StorageException` are commonly caused because of wrong 
`StorageReference` reference .

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-bucket-name>");

// Create a reference to "file"
StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("file.jpg");
```

Make sure the reference to the file is made correctly.

---

**Documentation Refrences**

[Details about creating Storage reference can be found in here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

[Details about the Storage Exception codes can be found in here for further refrences](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageException)

Answer (score 6):

**This Sorted me out**,  not a single line of code change ;) ,  All I needed to do was to update the firebase-storage lib.
In my case it was `'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.4.0'` and after updating it to `'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'` everything start working fine again.

Comment: Agree with this one, this is also the fix on mine.

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same exception but got over with it by simply granting Storage Permission to app from:

Settings > Apps > {My App} > Permissions > Enable Storage

The above part can also be done through Java code, I learned it in a tutorial for Android Marshmallow.
Also, make sure to declare permission for INTERNET and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android Manifest file.
However, if you are still getting the exception, try updating play services as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. It's not storage permission problem, i just changed the Firebase Storage Rules then solved.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Above are default rules which works fine. Changing the condition may cause Exception. Please check your condition before use.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

This problem may cause of authentication while uploading in firestore . You have to remove authentication part in the code of the rules of firebase storage.

Remove this and publish
:if request.auth != null;

Comment: Thank you it's work for me

Comment: 'You have to remove authentication part in the code' - why to remove the authentication part ? How can I keep the authentication feature and upload images as well ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue today.

- You need to have up to date google play services.
- At a minimum, Please enable anonymous authentication in firebase console.
- Steps to follow to authenticate anonymously.
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously
- You can also set bare minimum / no authentication in Rules(JSON in storage tab of console) (but it is not recommended as it is insecure).

Answer (score 1):

Enable anonymous authentication in firebase console.

Comment: After enabling also getting same exception

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I removed existed google.services.json file, download once again from firebase console and add it to my project.Now it is working successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same,

1. Update all the suggested dependencies from project structure
2. Update Google play services

Answer (score 1):

````
```private StorageReference mStorage;
final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("log_images");
Task<Uri> downloadurl = filepath.getDownloadUrl();```
````

check the above and last make sure the yourlatest
for latest version google search (android and firebase)
   'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the storage rules as below in firebase console/storage/rules

```html
allow read, write: if true;
```

2. Next you will need to uninstall firebase storage

```html
yarn remove @react-native-firebase/storage
```

3. Now install firebase storage

```html
yarn add @react-native-firebase/storage
```

It should ideally work, you could even try to replace the google-services file from project settings after Step 1.

The issue I feel is that you the firebase storage has somehow set the read and write permissions as false, so if you change it in firebase console, you will need to reinstall storage in your app to apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this issue, when I had not created the referenced folder/bucket in the Firebase Storage. Unlike Firebase Database, I think (I am not sure yet), the Storage reference will not create the bucket if it doesn't exist in the first place. So, create a folder first, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with checking if you have granted the Permission of Internet in Your Manifest.
2. Check if You have Granted The Correct Authorization Permission To Write To Your Storage in The "**Rules"** tab of your Storage.
3. Try **Logging** the reference to Your **Firebase Storage** as well as to the **File** You are trying to upload. Check if its the same as the Firebase Project You are Working On In The Browser.

In my case the project configuration was wrong, which is pretty much the first thing we do in the project. But hey! Its better than missing out on a ";"

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the storage reference is..  You need to put a proper URI of the file to upload in `putFile()` method.