# Firebase image upload issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
      An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
       Code: -13000 HttpResult: 400

```
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
  java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
      at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzcyp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzcyo(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/MainActivity: onFailure sendFileFirebase An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
```

here is code I have written for image upload

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(Util.URL_STORAGE_REFERENCE).child(Util.FOLDER_STORAGE_IMG);


final String name = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss", new Date()).toString();
StorageReference imageGalleryRef = storageReference.child(name + "_gallery");
UploadTask uploadTask = imageGalleryRef.putFile(file);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure sendFileFirebase " + e.getMessage());
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess sendFileFirebase");
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                FileModel fileModel = new FileModel("img", downloadUrl.toString(), name, "");
                ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(userModel, "", Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() + "", fileModel);                    
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(CHAT_REFERENCE).push().setValue(chatModel);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the `StorageReference` you used is correct?

Comment: yes, StorageReference with UploadTask like this :   UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file));

Comment: Possibly a problem with `storageReference`.  Similar stacktrace at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37543022/4815718.  Post the code that creates `storageReference`.

Comment: @qbix I have updated the code above

Comment: Hey check out this page.It might help you!                                                       https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/X37PwJs6I0A