# Firebase Storage - User does not have permission

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-storage

I have added a portion of my app which the user can upload a profile image but for some reason i get a firebase error saying i/user doesnt have permission even though the rules show it is accessible for all to read and write  given the auth is not null. I want users that have logged in to be allowed to read/write.

**My firebase storage rules**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**stacktrace:**

```
03-21 11:46:26.851 13033-13033/com.dogboy60.photoblog E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
                                                                      java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzLb(Unknown Source:21)
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzLa(Unknown Source:58)
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source:259)
                                                                          at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

03-21 11:46:26.865 13033-13033/com.dogboy60.photoblog E/Error here:: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543022/firebase-storage-is-giving-storageexception-while-trying-to-upload-images

Comment: @NileshRathod i have the following: 

private StorageReference storageReference;

//code

storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
//code 

StorageReference imagePath = storageReference.child("Profile Images").child(UUID +".jpeg");

Comment: nvm the getReferance gets the link, so i have what that page has. though it wont work

Comment: You should post the code and the complete stacktrace that shows that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Firebase rule like below code ..
remove only if condition.

```
service firebase.storage {
   match /b/sacred-age-861.appspot.com/o {
      match /{allPaths=**} {
         allow read, write;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: but will that not allow anyone to post/add to the storage? i only want logged in users

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allowing anybody to be able to do anything with your data use this:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```